# why can't I use this in my subroutine?

Tags: perl

I have the following:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ? ";
&checkDB( $sql , "bob" , "while"  );

sub checkDB(){

my $sth=$dbh->prepare($_[0]) or warn "$DBI::errstr";
$sth->execute( $_[1] ) or warn "$DBI::errstr";

print $_[2] . "\n"; # this works
    $_[2] ( my @rows= $sth -> fetchrow() ) { # this doesn't work
    blah, blah, blah
    }


}
```

I pass my sql statement, 'bob' and either a "while" or "unless" variable into the subroutine.
My subroutine will let me pass the "while" variable (it will print "while\n") but it won't let me use it to fetchrows. What am I doing wrong?

my exact error is "syntax error at script.pl near "}" "....works fine if I substitute $_[2] with the actual word "while"

Comment: Because Perl doesn't do keyword substitution like that. What exactly is the third parameter supposed to represent (other than `while`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use variable in place of keyword in perl. If you really must do such constructs, look at [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) - it lets you run arbitrary string as perl code.

Answer (score 2):

Because  `while` and `"while"` are different things.

You can't substitute arbitrary language constructs for strings.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you would need here is an [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), however this has evil written all over it. You definitely want to be sure that nothing in that code is tainted (coming from user). I think you probably should think very hard about why you would want to do this and if there isn't a better way (two different functions for example). I know we programmers like to be lazy, but evals are dangerous.

Comment: perhaps you could test the string, if it is "while" do the while loop, if it is "until" do an until loop. Some repeated code, but safer.

Comment: +1 for eval/evil pun (well actually for pointing out evilness). Seriously, either figure out how to make a loop that works as "while" if a flag is true and as "unless" if false; or modularize away the "loop" contents into a sub, and just to a conditional "while" or "until" (the abstraction of the contents avoids code duplication)